# Word 2016- How To Insert Row Below With Content Controls In All Cells of A Table- VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a table with 1 row and 5 columns (cells).

The following code successfully inserts a row below with 5 columns but only a content control into the first cell.

```
Dim oTable As table
Dim oCell As Cell
Dim oNewRow As Row
    Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    Set oNewRow = oTable.Rows.Add
    Set oCell = oNewRow.Cells(1)
    ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add wdContentControlRichText, oCell.Range
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
```

How do I enter content controls into all 5 cells in the row?

Comment: See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/27809-code-add-new-row-table.html#post87989, 
https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/13955-macro-add-row-table-word-form.html#post38461, 
https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/43603-multiple-dependent-dropdown-lists-table-add-new.html#post145675

Comment: Seems clear you need to either repeat the two lines above lbl_exit four more times (adjusting the cell index), or write a loop.

Comment: @Tim Williams- Thank you sir!

Comment: @MohamadBachrouche - if you edit your question please make it clear what you have changed. Anyone reading your question in the future will think the code you have included does not work.

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt- Thank you sir!

Comment: Also, for Word 2013 and later, should look into using the Repeating Section Content Control, which has nothing to do with a Word  "Section".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Tim Williams recommendation:

```
Dim oTable As table
Dim oCell As Cell
Dim oNewRow As Row
    Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    Set oNewRow = oTable.Rows.Add
    Set oCell = oNewRow.Cells(1)
    ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add wdContentControlRichText, oCell.Range
    Set oCell = oNewRow.Cells(2)
    ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add wdContentControlRichText, oCell.Range
    Set oCell = oNewRow.Cells(3)
    ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add wdContentControlRichText, oCell.Range
    Set oCell = oNewRow.Cells(4)
    ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add wdContentControlRichText, oCell.Range
    Set oCell = oNewRow.Cells(5)
    ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add wdContentControlRichText, oCell.Range
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
```